# Reactive dropdown menu in R shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

new to shiny here. I am creating a dashboard and have different categories and subcategories. what I am trying to do is as follows:

When the screen loads I would like all the categories and subcategories to be available for selection, but if I select category '1', then only 'sub1' and 'sub2' should be available for selection. So like it is being filtered by the category.
How would I implement this in the server file in shiny?
 a brief example of my code is as follows: (server is sudo code)

```
UI -->     
    dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
          menuItem("CSF2", tabName = "CSF2", icon=icon("bar-chart")),
            selectInput("category", "Select a category", c("1", "2"),
            selectInput("subcategory", "Select a subcategory",       c("sub1", "sub2", "sub3" "sub4"),
        )),


server--->
shinyServer(function(input,output){
    if (category_selected == 1){subcategoryOptions= c(sub1,sub2)}
    if (category_selected == 2){subcategoryOptions= c(sub3,sub4)}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

UI <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("CSF2", tabName = "CSF2", icon = icon("bar-chart")),
    selectInput("category", "Select a category", c("1", "2")),
    selectInput("subcategory", "Select a subcategory",       
                c("sub1", "sub2", "sub3", "sub4"))
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observe({
    updateSelectInput(
      session, "subcategory", "Select a subcategory",
      choices = switch(input$category,
        "1" = c("sub1", "sub2"),
        "2" = c("sub3", "sub4"))
    )
  })

}

shinyApp(UI, server)
```